# Only need 'most recent' Task - best practices for cancelling/ignoring?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, task

I have a task that looks like this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew <object>(LongMethod);
task.ContinueWith(TaskCallback, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

LongMethod calls a long running service, during which I can’t (or at least, don’t think I can), constantly poll a cancellation token to see if it has been cancelled. However, I am interested in ‘cancelling’, or ignoring, the callback method.

When the TaskCallback is called, I am only interested in the ‘result’ *if* it is the from the most recent task (let us assume that the service that LongMethod calls preserves order, and also assume that the user can click the button numerous times, but only the latest one is relevant).

I have modified my code in the following way: after a task is created, I add it to the top of a stack. In the TaskCallback, I check to see if the task that has been passed to the callback is the most recent one (i.e. a TryPeek at the top of the stack). If it is not, I just ignore the result.

```
private ConcurrentStack<Task> _stack = new ConcurrentStack<Task>();

private void OnClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew < object >( LongMethod);
    task.ContinueWith(TaskCallback, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    _stack.Push(task);
 }


private void TaskCallback(Task<object> task)
{
    Task topOfStack;
    if(_stack.TryPeek(out topOfStack)) //not the most recent
    {
        if (task != topOfStack) return;
    }
    //else update UI
}
```

I am quite certain that this isn’t a ‘best practices’ solution. But what is? Passing and maintaing cancellation tokens doesn’t really seem all that elegant, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally find the following approach to be the most elegant:

```
// Cancellation token for the latest task.
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

private void OnClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // If a cancellation token already exists (for a previous task),
    // cancel it.
    if (this.cancellationTokenSource != null)
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    // Create a new cancellation token for the new task.
    this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = this.cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    // Start the new task.
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(LongMethod, cancellationToken);

    // Set the task continuation to execute on UI thread,
    // but only if the associated cancellation token
    // has not been cancelled.
    task.ContinueWith(TaskCallback, 
        cancellationToken, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void TaskCallback(Task<object> task)
{
    // Just update UI
}
```

Comment: I think you should pass the `CancellationToken` also to `StartNew()`. That way, the `Task` can be canceled before it's started.

Comment: @svick: Under what circumstance would that be possible? Per the above logic, the `CancellationToken` may only be cancelled from the UI thread, whilst the new task may start executing asynchronously on a background thread as soon as the `StartNew` method is called.

Comment: If you call `StartNew()` it doesn't mean the `Task` is actually immediately started, it's just scheduled on the `ThreadPool`. If the pool is busy, it might take a while before it's started. In such situation, the `Task` might be canceled before it starts running, if you give it the `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @svick: It seems you’re right (although I still can’t find any source clarifying *when* the `CancellationToken` is internally checked). I’m editing the code per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you cannot cancel your long running task but want the process to be instantly aborted from the users point of view when he cancels.

Start a cancel task in parallel with your long running task. Continue off of `Task.WhenAny(longRunningTask, cancelTask)` and check, if the completed task was the long running task or the cancel task. You can then decide what to do (show results or update UI).

When you cancel the "cancel task" the continuation will instantly fire.

Comment: How is that better than what Douglas suggested: passing the `CancellationToken` to `ContinueWith()`?

Comment: You can hook up a continuation which runs in case the user cancels. This is *not* the same as just executing code as part of the cancel click handler: The cancel click might arrive just after the long running task has completed, causing a race between the success continuation and the cancel code.