# Run only the current task and the most recently queued task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have some methods. We'll call them "TurnOn" and "TurnOff". Each returns an unstarted task (as in System.Threading.Tasks.Task). Once started, the task takes about a second to complete. I have some code to queue these with the Task.ContinueWith method (shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/run-control-tasks-asynchronously-using-tpl)). The problem is that I only really want the currently running task (if any) plus the most recently requested task to run. Presently, if my user toggles the on/off switch ten times in a second, it takes twenty seconds for my code to catch up. It's only the final request that I care about. How can I achieve this? I can't see a way inside the ContinueWith method to know if there is another ContinueWith method after it. I've been looking at the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163769/only-need-most-recent-task-best-practices-for-cancelling-ignoring), but can't quite see how to apply it.

**Update:** this is now available in the library here: https://github.com/BrannonKing/Kts.ActorsLite . It's named "MostRecent..."

Comment: What about disabling buttons? E.g. disable TurnOn after task is started, until it will become finîshed?

Comment: It's a joystick button, so I can't exactly disable it. Also, I don't want to skip any state transitions on it in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a class that keeps track of the currently executing task, the action to be run next, and that runs the "next" action whenever the previous action finishes.  The key here is that if the next action has a value when you go to enqueue a new one you can simply replace `nextTask` rather than adding another continuation.

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private Task currentlyExecuting = Task.FromResult(false);
    public Task continuation = null;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Action nextTask = null;
    private object key = new object();
    public Task Queue(Action action)
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            if (nextTask == null)
            {
                nextTask = action;
                ScheduleContinuation();
                return continuation;
            }
            else
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                nextTask = action;
                ScheduleContinuation();
                return continuation;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ScheduleContinuation()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;
        continuation = currentlyExecuting.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            lock (key)
            {
                currentlyExecuting = Task.Run(nextTask);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                nextTask = null;
            }
        }, cts.Token);
    }
}
```

While you *could* accept unstarted tasks here, and it's a pretty trivial re-write to do so, I consider it better practice here to accept a delegate and to create and then start the task when it is ready to be started.

Comment: How does this execute the action in the case where `nextTask == null`?

Comment: @Brannon What do you mean?  If the next task is null, it sets the given item as the next task, and creates a continuation to run it when the current task finishes.

Comment: @Brannon The first revision handled that issue.  The updated code simply ensures that if an operation is "skipped" that the task created for it is marked as "canceled" rather than being a task that represents the operation that skipped it.

Comment: I have been getting some rare exceptions where `nextTask` in the line `currentlyExecuting = Task.Run(nextTask);` is null. Can you see any way that can happen?

Comment: @Brannon Pretty sure I found it.  If a task was cancelled after it was started it would continue on to null out `nextTask`.  I added in a check to ensure that if the continuation is canceled it won't do that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious about the choice of "throw" vs "if (!token.IsCanceled)". I'm just not sure it's an exceptional situation...

Comment: @Brannon If the cancellation token cancels the task before it has completed, it should be cancelled, it shouldn't run to completion and have it's status indicate that it completed successfully, because it didn't.  It was cancelled.  If you specifically want it's status to indicate that it completed successfully, rather than being canceled, then by all means, make that change.

Comment: This is such an amazing piece of code which isn't upvoted enough! Note that there is still an issue with `_nextTask` being null. If queue is created fast enough, continuation threads will queue up and run at unpredictable order and every once in a while you'd still get null reference exception. To remedy this, the check should be at the top of the continuation lock. Or simply surround both lines with `if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)` whatever works best. I love how this is "just" a class for Servy :).

Comment: The solution, including a TaskScheduler implementation (@AbleArcher) is now available at https://github.com/BrannonKing/Kts.ActorsLite . See the "MostRecent..." classes there.